# is it possible to move my return values around in this method?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, constructor, return-value

I'm writing a code to create a new object with key metadata being provided by a user input form. I'm wondering if there's a way to return the object (q) in the try block and not at the end of the method?

Here's my current code with some notes about how I want it all to look:

```
    public NewSearchQuery GetEntry()
    {
        //pull all input field information and store ready for validation
        string name = Convert.ToString(Companies.SelectedItem);
        string location = String.Concat(Convert.ToString(Property.Text), " ", Convert.ToString(SearchLocation.Text).ToLower());
        string searchtype = Convert.ToString(Search.SelectedItem);
        var q = new NewSearchQuery();

        //check all required input fields are filled in
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(location) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchtype))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure you have filled in all the required fields (*) before proceeding", "Insufficient Information");
            this.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                q.GetFormData(name, location, searchtype, Paid.Checked); //replace this with a constructor for var q
                q.Contract = ThisAddIn.GetContract(q.Name);
                q.CreateIdNum();
                q.CreateFilePath(q.Contract, q.RefNum);
                q.CalculateFees();
            }
            catch (Exception d)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(d)); //return null if the try fails
            }
        }
        return q; //relocate this to the try block
    }
```

I want to make these changes because I suspect that returning the q value irrespective of the process working or not is causing my winform to error out it if try to exit it prematurely.

Is there a way I can get around the inevitable 'not all code paths return a value' error?

Comment: Have you tried putting the return in the try block? and returning null at the end.

Comment: Decide what you want to do when this call fails. Throw? Return null? Exit the application?

Comment: Sure you can. But your method promises that it will return a `NewSearchQuery` (or thow an exception). so you have to return one (maybe null) also from the `if` branch and the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your method as follows:

```
public NewSearchQuery GetEntry()
{
    //pull all input field information and store ready for validation
    string name = Convert.ToString(Companies.SelectedItem);
    string location = String.Concat(Convert.ToString(Property.Text), " ", Convert.ToString(SearchLocation.Text).ToLower());
    string searchtype = Convert.ToString(Search.SelectedItem);
        

    //check all required input fields are filled in
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(location) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchtype))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please ensure you have filled in all the required fields (*) before proceeding", "Insufficient Information");
       this.ShowDialog();
       return null;
    }

    try
    {
        var q = new NewSearchQuery();
        q.GetFormData(name, location, searchtype, Paid.Checked); //replace this with a constructor for var q
        q.Contract = ThisAddIn.GetContract(q.Name);
        q.CreateIdNum();
        q.CreateFilePath(q.Contract, q.RefNum);
        q.CalculateFees();
        return q;
    }
    catch (Exception d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(d)); //return null if the try fails
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now all code paths return a value. I omitted the `else` block, because if you leave the method inside the `if` block. This means, that the code following the `if` block is never executed when your condition is true, as it would be with the `else` block. The advantage of this is that you don't have so much nested bracings, which makes the code easier to understand.

Be sure to check whether the return value is not null, otherwise you might have a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Write a return statement within every single block.

```
if(something)
{
    return value;
}
else
{
    try
    {
        return value;
    }
    catch
    {
        return value;
    }   
}
```